# How to convert List into HashBasedTable using Java 8?

Tags: java-8, hashmap, guava, guava-table

How can we convert a List into HashBasedTable in Java8?

Current Code is like:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.guava.HashBasedTable;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.guava.Table;

List<ApplicationUsage> appUsageFromDB = computerDao.findAllCompAppUsages(new HashSet<>(currentBatch));
Table<String, String, Integer> table = HashBasedTable.create();
for(ApplicationUsage au: appUsageFromDB) {
  table.put(au.getId(), au.getName(), au);
}
```

I need to store composite key in this and later fetch the same.

Answer (score 2):

If those internals are guava-21 at least, you could do via their own collector, but I do not see anything wrong with what you are doing with a simple loop.

```
Table<String, String, ApplicationUsage> result =
        appUsageFromDB.stream()
                      .collect(ImmutableTable.toImmutableTable(
                          ApplicationUsage::getId,
                          ApplicationUsage::getName,
                          Function.identity()
                      ));
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should never rely on internal packages, just add Guava to you project explicitly. You can use [`Tables#toTable`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#toTable-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-) collector, if you want to have mutable table as a result, otherwise immutable one as presented in @Eugene's answer is just fine:

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable;
import com.google.common.collect.Table;
import com.google.common.collect.Tables;

// ...

    Table<String, String, ApplicationUsage> table2 = appUsageFromDB.stream()
            .collect(Tables.toTable(
                    ApplicationUsage::getId,
                    ApplicationUsage::getName,
                    au -> au,
                    HashBasedTable::create
            ));
```

Also, your code doesn't compile, because it expects `Integer` as table value, but you're adding `ApplicationUsage` in your loop. Change types and third argument in table collector accordingly if needed.

Comment: Thanks. Any reason why should we not use internals?

Comment: @fatherazrael 1) It's rarely a good idea to rely on internals of anything 2) You don't know which version is used 3) The version used can change with upgrade of the framework or even completely go away.